# Draggable выбранных элементов списка

Tags: jquery, drag-n-drop

Есть список с checkbox:

```
<ul class="attach-list">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]"> Item 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]"> Item 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]"> Item 3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="items[]"> Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Нужно сделать возможность перетаскивания только выбранных элементов списка. Сейчас перетаскивается весь список - и выбранные и не выбранные:

```
$(".attach-list").draggable({
    helper: clone,
    ....
});
```

Делаю так:

```
$(".attach-list").draggable({
    helper: function() {
        return $('input[name="items[]"]:checked').closest('li');
    },
    .....
});
```

Проблема в том, что при перемещении элемент исчезает из списка, т.е. helper работает как original, а нужно чтобы был как clone.

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался сам. Вот так работает:

```
helper: function (e, ui) {
    ul = $(this).clone(true);
    ul.find('li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('input').prop('checked') === false) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    return ul;
},
```